# How voting system works?

Tags: support, voting

Do all votes have the same effect on reputation?

Is there any policy in which first `n` votes will increase/decrease the reputation by `j`, and after `n` votes reputation will increase/decrease by `k` votes?

Comment: In short: there's no such policy. It's always the same amount following the simple rules posted in the answer.

Comment: Also worth to mention in this context - after enough downvotes on certain user posts, he will get automatic ban - either questions or answers - if he/she does not have enough upvotes as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rules are such:

- downvotes cost 1 rep for the downvoter (answers only) and 2 rep to the downvotee
- upvotes on questions give 5 rep
- upvotes on answers give 10 rep
- the daily reputation cap from upvotes only is 200 rep

The values of the different upvotes/downvotes do not change (outside of the daily cap).

Reputation gains from accepting answers, bounties and other bonuses are exempt from the cap.